# How to use multiple @Field on the same value with beanio?

Tags: java, bean-io

I'm using `org.beanio` to parse fixed-length records.

Unfortunately, there are `price` values where the integer and fractional part of the price is distributed to different locations.

Question: is it possible to define two `@Field`s to one single value, and extract different parts of the `BigDecimal` via `format`?

```
@Field(at = 20, length = 6, format = ...<the integer part>)
@Field(at = 100, length = 2, format = ...<the fractional part>) 
private BigDecimal price;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible , but you can simply map to 2 other fields and calculate the value ,

```
@Field(at = 20, length = 6)
private Integer priceWholeAmt;

@Field(at = 100, length = 2) 
private Integer priceChange;

public BigDecimal getPrice(){
   return new BigDecimal(priceWholeAmt).add(new BigDecimal(priceChange/100));
}
```